# Riemann zeta function reflection formula and limit of $\zeta(1-z_n)/\zeta(z_n)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Within the critical strip, the Riemann zeta functional equation: 
$$\zeta(1-s)= \chi(s)\zeta(s)$$
implies that if $s_0$ is a non trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ located off the critical line (if any exists ...), then $1-s_0$ must also be a zero.
I am interested in better understanding how to approach a slight variation of the following limit:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\zeta(1-z_n)}{\zeta(z_n)}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\chi(z_n) = \chi(s_o) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1) $$
whereby the $z_n$ are taken inside a neighbourhood $U$ of $s_0$ sufficiently small as not to contain other zeros, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}z_n = s_0$. Here is the slight variation I am interested in thoroughly understanding:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\zeta(1-w_n)}{\zeta(z_n)}$$
whereby $w_n$ represents a sequence of values (in $U$ ) different from the $z_n$, but whose limit is also $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}w_n = s_0$. Is $(1)$ still valid ? My reasoning is that $\zeta(1-w_n)$ could be written as $\zeta(1-z_n)+\Delta(w_n)$, whereby $\Delta(w_n)$ represents an error term vanishing as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Thus: 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\zeta(1-w_n)}{\zeta(z_n)}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\chi(z_n) + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Delta (w_n)}{\zeta(z_n)}= \chi(s_o)  \ \ ? \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (2) $$
this would be true it it were possible to prove that for $n \rightarrow \infty$ said error term $\Delta (w_n)$ vanishes at a rate faster than $\zeta (z_n)$. If such an approach makes sense at all, and if you believe that it might be amenable to a rigorous proof, what specific theorems of holomorphic functions theory would you suggest to apply? Many thanks for any suggestion you may have..

Comment: See any text on complex analysis. If $F(s)$ is analytic and has a simple zero at $s=a$ then $F(s) = F'(a) (s-a)+\mathcal{O}(|s-a|^2)$. Thus you are looking at $$\frac{\zeta(1-w_n)}{\zeta(z_n)} = \frac{\zeta'(1-s_0) (w_n-s_0)+\mathcal{O}(|w_n-s_0|^2)}{\zeta'(s_0) (z_n-s_0)+\mathcal{O}(|z_n-s_0|^2)}$$ where $\zeta'(1-s_0)= \chi(s_0)\zeta'(1-s_0)$ by the functional equation

Comment: Thanks reuns. I am correcting just a minor typo $\zeta'(1-s_0)= \chi(s_0)\zeta'(s_0)$. So, would I be correct to proceed as follows?

Comment: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\zeta(1-w_n)}{\zeta(z_n)}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\zeta'(1-s_0) (w_n-s_0)}{\zeta'(s_0) (z_n-s_0)}=\chi(s_0) \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(w_n-s_0)}{(z_n-s_0)}$$ so that my question (2) would be true only if the two sequences $w_n$ and $z_n$ are explicitly chosen in order that the limit of the RHS factor $(w_n-s_0)/(z_n-s_0)$ is 1?

Comment: thus implying that $w_n = z_n$ ? circularly going back where I started from ... so that (2) is in fact not true in general, when the $w_n$ differ from the $z_n$.

Comment: at least in the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Do you understand the O notations ? Of course you need $w_n-s_0 = C(z_n-s_0)+o(|z_n-s_0|)$ for the above limits to converge. The main point is that this is not specific to $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: ok, I was not explicitly assuming that the $z_n$ and the $w_n$ are indeed chosen so that those limits exist. The simplest counter-example to (2) that comes to my mind is $z_n = s_0+\frac{1}{n}$ and $w_n=s_0+\frac{1}{n^2}$, so that limit (2) vanishes instead of being $\chi(s_0)$

Comment: Then $C= 0$ and the limit converges.

Comment: Also what do you get if the zero is double instead of simple ?